# How compare input text value with a data value of a csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, csv

Hi I want compare input text value with a data value of a csv file, and if is equals then show me the valitadion message. I have this code.

```
<label>Product series number <button onclick="myValidation()">Validate!</button><span id="mensaje"></span><br>
   <input type="number" name="numero_serie" id="mySerie" value="" size="40" placeholder="Write here!"></span></label> 

function myValidation() {
var text;
var series = document.getElementById("mySerie").value;

switch(series) {
    case "959189132":
    case "2572331":
    case "44265108":

    text = "Validado";
    document.getElementById("register").disabled = false;
    break;
    default:
    text = "Número no valido";
    document.getElementById("mySerie").value = "";

}
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = text;
```

}